# How can I find the minimum key value from an std::vector of std::map values?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, vector, stl

I have an `std::vector` of `std::map` values:

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>> dataPoints;
```

I would like to find the lowest `low` value, 74.0. Here is my application so far:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>> dataPoints;

    dataPoints.push_back({{{"high", 77.0}, {"low", 74.0}}});
    dataPoints.push_back({{{"high", 78.0}, {"low", 75.0}}});
    dataPoints.push_back({{{"high", 79.0}, {"low", 76.0}}});
    dataPoints.push_back({{{"high", 80.0}, {"low", 77.0}}});
    dataPoints.push_back({{{"high", 81.0}, {"low", 78.0}}});

    return 0;
}
```

The closest I have found so far is:

```
double min = std::min_element(dataPoints.begin(), dataPoints.end(), [](std::map<std::string, double> &a, std::map<std::string, double> &b) { return (a["low"] < b["low"]); })["low"];
```

But this does not quite work.

In JavaScript, I could achieve this as follows:

```
low = _.min(_.map(dataSegment, function(dataPoints) {
    return dataPoint.low;
}));
```

Comment: Do you always have a `map` of two entries? Because if so, you can get better performance by using `std::vector<std::array<std::pair<std::string, double>,2>>`

Comment: I would suggest to use std::pair instead of map to store 2 values. Like std::set <std::pair <double, double>>.

Comment: @StoryTeller Nice! Thank you. How noticeable a performance increase? Also, what is the "2" parameter in th vector definition?

Comment: Youd have to benchmark to see how better it can be exactly. But using contiguous data structures (which vector, array and pair are) can reduce cache misses, due to locality of memory. As for the 2, it's the std::array fixes size.

Comment: A comment about the answers you have gotten so far suggesting using `std::pair`: `std::pair` is almost always the wrong tool for the job. You should instead define a `struct` with named fields. `struct Pair { double high; double low; }; std::vector<Pair> dataPoints;`. Defining a data type is slightly more code than using `std::make_pair`, but makes the code so much more readable.

Comment: Agreed as far as code readability. There may still be performance implications when processing large amounts of data as I am, but I'm no C++ expert. Also, I have to use an `std::map` because I need to reference values by variable value key names, and I'll have over 100 key/value pairs in each map within the vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `min_element`, not `max_element`. And it returns an iterator so you'll want to dereference it.

And I suppose you probably don't want to insert a zero if `"low"` is not in the map. So `at` instead of `[]`; this also allows us to constify the whole thing across the board.

```
double min = std::min_element(dataPoints.cbegin(), dataPoints.cend(),
              [](const std::map<std::string, double> &a,
                 const std::map<std::string, double> &b) {
                     return a.at("low") < b.at("low"); 
              })->at("low");
```

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I posted from my phone :) Thank you for finding that typo -- fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Map is used to store key/value pairs. There is no point using a map if you have 2 keys that are same all the time. You don't need these keys sorted either.

If given first value is high and second low then you can use:

```
std::pair <double, double>
```

This way, every time you add a new value you save two std::string sized memory space.

A vector is useful in storing unordered sequence. Depending on whether you want your data to be sorted you can use a set here with a compare based on high or low. This will speed up finding min value to constant time.

Set:

```
std::set <std::pair <double, double>>.
```

Set is a sorted container. With set you can use **begin()** if your lowest is at the top or **end()** if it at the bottom.

If you choose **unsorted** then use **std::vector**. If your container changes frequently and can be **large**, then you may need **std::deque**. If your container has a **fixed size** and you are not going to modify it then use **std::array**. You may use **min_element** here in this case. This type of search is linear time.

**EDIT**

If you want to stick with std::vector < std::map< std::string, double>> the following should work:

```
//min_element returns std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>>::iterator
auto minDataPoint = std::min_element(dataPoints.begin(), dataPoints.end(), [](std::map<std::string, double> &a, std::map<std::string, double> &b) { 
    return (a["low"] < b["low"]); 
});

std::cout<<"low "<<(*minDataPoint)["low"];
```

tested here: http://ideone.com/sdG6fk

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why I would want std::pair <double, double> with the set or vector. I want to be able to access data values associatively by key; e.g. dataPoint["low"]. Wouldn't using std::pair <double, double> make this impossible?

Comment: If you used a pair dataPoint["high"] will become dataPoint.first and dataPoint["low"] will become dataPoint.second. You do not need the keys in your case since all you have is "high" and "low" (Unless you have more?). Associating 2 keys is just redundant. The only catch it you got to make sure the values you enter into the pair is in that order.

Comment: Yeah I actually have more...about 100. high, low, open, close, rsi7, rsi5, stochasticK, stochasticD, etc.

Comment: Edited my answer for std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>>